# Tensorflow: How to train a Linear Regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning to train a Linear Regression model via TensorFlow.
It's quite a simple formula:

> y = **W** * x + **b**

I have generated a sample data:

[image]

After the model training I can see in Tensorboard that "**W**" is correct when "**b**" goes a completely wrong way. So, Loss is quite high.

**[Here](https://github.com/VictorDDT/uploadfiles/blob/master/TF/Linear%20Regression%20Training.py)** is my code.

[image]

**QUESTION**

Why is "**b**" being trained a wrong way?

Shall I do something with the optimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On line 16](https://github.com/VictorDDT/uploadfiles/blob/master/TF/Linear%20Regression%20Training.py#L16), you are adding gaussian noise with a standard deviation of 300!!

`noise = np.random.normal(scale=n, size=(N, 1))`

Try using:

`noise = np.random.normal(size=(N, 1))`

That's using mean=0 and std=1 (standard Gaussian noise).

Also, 20k iterations is more than enough (in this problem) for training.

For a more comprehensive explanation of what is happening, look at your plot. Given an `x` value, the possible values for `y` have thousands of units of difference. That means that there are a lot of lines that explain your data. Hence a lot of values for B are possible, but no matter which one you choose (even the true b value) all of them are going to have a big loss.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Hernandez and Misza for you comments! I think I see your point. But what shall I do in a real case when I'm not able to "change" training data? Shall I clean the training data to remove spikes?

Comment: If the training data have such variability there is not much to do. You could try a different model in that case, cleaning outliers, standardizing the data, but it may still be hard to find any patterns

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to hear somebody's opinion about that. Please post here any other thoughts about that, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The optimization is working correctly but the problem is with the `b` parameter whose estimation is much more heavily influenced by the initial "roll of dice" of `noise` (which has a standard deviation of `N`) than the actual value of `b_true` (which is much smaller than `N`).